# Rabbinic responsa on Remembering the fallen IDF soldiers

Tags: halacha-theory, army-military-war, state-of-israel

*I know it is a heavy and very "politically" loaded question, but I'd try my best to formulate it in a most neutral way:*

24 thousands of R' Akivah students allegedly died of their own sins some 2000 years ago, and we commemorate this every year for 7 weeks with some Mourning Halochos during Omer.

More than [23 thousands](https://www.izkor.gov.il/) of Jewish soldiers (and civils) were killed defending the lives of the Jewish people in the Promised Land for over a century.

AFAIK there are no accepted Halachic or Minhagim ways of commemorating this fact, at least in *any Orthodox movements* in Israel including the Mercaz Harav- no special prayer, no Tehhilim, no Rabbi Shiurim, no fasting, etc (*I can't deny the existence of some private [Rabbis] initiatives, but those didn't make it into a "tradition"*).

Are there any Rabbinical responsa on this topic? Wasn't any Rabbi since the establishment of the Jewish State asked about this?

Comment: Do you only want Rabbinical responsa?

Comment: Do the Karaites have a lot to say on the subject, @David? :)

Comment: @JoshK LoL, I am asking if he wants official responsa from recognized world poskim or can we give him our educated opinions? I happen to think the answer is pretty simple.

Comment: Dude, you have to get out sometime. Go tomorrow to any Yeshivat Hesder. See if it's a regularly programmed day. Your claims are ridiculous. Stop making claims about all of Orthodox Judaism if you haven't a clue what goes on outside the Haredi world.

Comment: @DoubleAA Enlighten me - what do their Rabbonim say? Did HaRay"A Cook or his followers institute a Minhag? Maybe I didn't hear.

Comment: Special Shiurim, Tehillim, etc.